# Ksh script removes linefeed when sent in email from text file

Tags: unix, ksh, mailx

I have a script which sends and email that reads a listing from a text file ($list_file). However when I receive the email I see that the line feed is removed and the listing shows in one line. How can I make it show that each entry corresponds to one line?

Email Notification:

```
File Transfer Listing

file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
```

Script:

```
echo "File Transfer Listing" > $mail_file
echo "" >> $mail_file
echo `cat $list_file` >> $mail_file
echo "" >> $mail_file
mailx -s "File Listing" myemail@email.com < $mail_file
```

Contents of $list_file:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
```

Contents of $mail_file:

```
File Transfer Listing

file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is not due to the ksh code that generates the email, but it is a feature of Outlook. Outlook tries to beautify the email.
When you open the email in Outlook, you see a message that extra line breaks have been removed. When you always mail to one client, you can configure Outlook with Tools --> Options  --> E-mail Options --> Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages.
A work-around is including an empty space character at the end of each line. 
Try this:

```
sed 's/$/ /' "${mail_file}" | mailx -s "File Listing" myemail@email.com
```